# SFTP Connection closed prematurely

Tags: phpseclib

Here's the result of a SFTP connection :

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SFTP.php');

define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);


$sftp = new Net_SFTP(
    SERVER,
    FTP_PORT
);

if (!$sftp->login(FTP_LOGIN, FTP_PASSWORD))
{
    echo 'Login failed.'.'<br>';
    echo $sftp->getLog().'<br>';
    echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();
}
else
{
    echo 'Login successful.'.'<br>';
    echo $sftp->pwd();
}
```

Notice: Connection closed prematurely in /home/www/default/sftp/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 2992
Login failed.

-> NET_SFTP_INIT (0.048s) 00000000 00:00:00:03 ....

The connection is working with FileZilla

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the SSH2 logs? eg. do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);` instead of `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);`. Thanks!

Comment: I was using phpseclib 0.3.6.
If I use phpseclib 0.3.5, it is working...

Comment: @neubert :

    <-
    00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:6d:6f:64:5f:73:66:74:70  SSH-2.0-mod_sftp
    00000010  2f:30:2e:39:2e:38:0d:0a                          /0.9.8..
    
    ->
    00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:70:68:70:73:65:63:6c:69  SSH-2.0-phpsecli
    00000010  62:5f:30:2e:33:20:28:6d:63:72:79:70:74:2c:20:62  b_0.3 (mcrypt, b
    00000020  63:6d:61:74:68:29:0d:0a                          cmath)..
    
    <- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.0993, network: 0.0001s)
    00000000  1d:d0:12:9c:10:b9:a1:a9:48:43:a0:a6:a7:8e:22:73  ........HC...."s

Comment: Can you copy / paste the contents on pastebin? Looks like SO truncated what you posted and even if it didn't all the new lines have been removed, which makes it nigh impossible to read. Also, if you could do it for both 0.3.5 and 0.3.6 that'd be good. Thanks..